# Cucumber step definiton not found - InteliJ Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

I have following problem. I have feature file as follows:

```
Feature: Serve coffee
  Coffee should not be served until paid for
  Coffee should not be served until the button has been pressed
  If there is no coffee left then money should be refunded

  Scenario: Buy last coffee
    Given there are 1 coffees left in the machine
    And I have deposited 1$
    When I press the coffee button
    Then I should be served a coffee
```

InteliJ highlights Given, And etc as missing step definitons. I generate definitions and InteliJ still doesn't recognize them. I'm using [Cucumber gradle plugin](https://github.com/samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin) with following configuration:

```
cucumber {
    formats = ['pretty','json:build/cucumber.json','junit:build/cucumber.xml']
    glueDirs = ['src/test/resources/step_definitions']
    featureDirs = ['src/test/resources/features']
}
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong there. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to check whether you have a correctly installed Cucumber for Java plugin in Intellij Idea. (Settings/Plugins).
2. Try to review your features and glue parameters. Cucumber by default will look for features to src/test/resources folder and for step definitions - to src/test/java. (actually in glueDirs option you have set path to steps in resources folder). 
   So try to modify your runner options like:

   ```
   cucumber {
   formats = ['pretty','json:build/cucumber.json','junit:build/cucumber.xml']
   glueDirs = ['step_definitions']
   featureDirs = ['features']
   }
   ```

Also in case of any problems you can try to use classpath in options:

```
cucumber {
formats = ['pretty','json:build/cucumber.json','junit:build/cucumber.xml']
glueDirs = ['classpath:step_definitions']
featureDirs = ['classpath:features']
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cucumber plugin for IntelliJ. Make sure that you have it installed.

The steps in your feature file will be marked as missing step definition until this plugin is installed.